# Overlaying the google map API with custom paths (iOS Development)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, overlay

I am trying to find out how to overlay/create custom paths within the google map api.
i.e. Around a certain area I have a map of cycle paths which are not already placed into the google maps.

Basically if someone can point me in the right direction by linking me or providing me with a few steps to get started that would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[iOS MapLayerDemo](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo) and [MTLocation](https://github.com/myell0w/MTLocation)may be a good place to look after.